# Rails search form submit to show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, controller

I am trying to set up a form in a Rails view to submit an id back to the show method in the controller. My form uses autocomplete to set the hidden id field:

```
<%= form_tag students_path, id: 'search_student_name', method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search_name, '', size: 30 %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using the standard controller 'show' method generated by the scaffold:

```
# GET /students/1
# GET /students/1.json
def show
  @student = student_scope.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @student }
  end
end
```

I'd be grateful for any advice on the combination of form url / post method / additional routes to get this to work. Is this the way you'd normally do this is Rails, or should I set up a new controller method to handle the submitted form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain how does it use autocomplete to fill your user id?

Comment: @Zippie I'm updating the hidden field with javascript on selecting the item. students.js.coffee : `$('#search_student_name #search_name').autocomplete
      minLength: 3,
      source: "/students/search_name_suggestions",
      select: (event, ui) ->
        $("#search_student_name #id").val ui.item.value
        # update what is displayed in the textbox
        @value = ui.item.label
        $('#search_student_name').submit()
        false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not exactly a Restful show, you should create a new action, search.

```
#routes.rb
post 'search' => 'students#search'

#student_controller.rb
def search
   @student = Student.find_by_name params[:search_name]
   render action: 'show'
end
```

The form doesn't need to send the :id as far as I can tell.

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= input_tag :search_name, type: 'text' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you @cmaitchison, that's working now. I'm using :id because the name is actually first_name and last_name, and I can populate the :id field with the autocomplete. I thought it would simplify the search query and only return a single value (in case of duplicate names). Thanks again.

Comment: in rails3: `post 'search', :to => 'studnets#search'`